# Python class fuction that takes self variable as argument

Tags: python

I want to write a function that sets a self variable to `None`, but it feels very wrong to write a million functions for each variable.

I want to do something like:

```
class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
       self.duck = None
       self.dog = None
   def makeduck(self):
       self.duck = "Duck"
   def makedog(self):
       self.dog = "Dog"
   def deleteVar(self,var):
       self.var = None # or del self.var
```

I want to do this because the variables tend to be very large and I don't want to overload my ram so I have to delete some not needed vars depending on the context.

Comment: Do you know how much space a string consumes, do you how much ram you have?? Don't optimize prematurely. I doubt you have a million variables and even if that still would not be a problem other than bad design.

Comment: In general, if you're _that_ memory-constrained, Python is the wrong language. Anyhow, what's your actual specific technical question?

Comment: ...in general, it would make a separate class for each type so you can use `__slots__` if you're serious about constraining memory usage. See [Usage of `__slots__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)

Comment: Why? Why do you need a method for this at all? Note, it doesn't *delete* anything

Comment: Why is it important why i need it for? If i explain my whole project it would massively miss the point of a concise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Although having a clear separation between what should be program structure: variables, and data: text inside strings, Python allows one to retrieve and operate on variables or attributes given their name.

In this case, you will want to use the `setattr` and `delattr`calls: both take an instance, an attribute name, given as textual data (a string), and operate on them like the corresponding assignment (self.var = xxx) and deleting (del self.var ). statements (but, as you intend to use, with "var" being a variable containign the actual attribute name).

```
def deleteVar(self, var):
    # setattr(self, var, None). #<- sets attribute to None
    delattr(self, var). # <- deletes attribute.
```

(for completeness: there is also the `getattr` call which allows attribute retrieval on the same bases)

That said: the memory usage of hard-coded variables, even if you have tens of them, will likely be negligible in a Python process.
Having tens of different "deleter" methods, however, would indeed be clumsy, and there are situations were your code might be more elegant by passing your attributes as data, as you intent.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know this exists.